# Change table td using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, simple-html-dom

I am new to Javascript so take it easy on me. I want to change data inside a table using javascript. I have looked everywhere for a suitable tutorial but I haven't found any. This is my code.

```js
function trans() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var row = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[2];
  var td = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

  td.innerHTML = "Julius";
}
```

```css
**css**
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: calibri;
}
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
thead {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
tbody {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.caption {
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table id="table" title="Employment status verses Living Conditions">
    <caption>Employment status verses Living Conditions</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3" class="caption">Employment status verses Living Conditions</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Condition</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Antony</td>
      <td>Employed</td>
      <td>Poor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grace</td>
      <td>Student</td>
      <td>Wealthy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Sponsored</td>
      <td>Self actualization</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Christine</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="center"><i>Unknown</i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">James and John</td>
      <td>Fishermen</td>
      <td>Spiritual</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brothers</td>
      <td>Disciples</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button onclick="trans()">Change name</button>
</body>

</html>
```

When I run the code it gives me the following error,

```
  {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: table.getElementByTagName is not a function",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 96,
  "colno": 15
}
```

I have changed the `getElementByTagName` to `getElementsByTagName` but it is still giving me an error, What is wrong with my code and what can I do to fix it. Find my jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/AntonyMN/7m82n4ft/4/)

Comment: it's `getElementsByTagName()` you are missing an **s**

Comment: Remember you have tr even in thead so change the row to table.getElementByTagName("table > tr")[1] because the row can be found but data will be undefined since there are no td's in th(from thead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:
[Code snippet](https://plnkr.co/edit/V78gMWiFLi5XNxCTIn3f?p=preview)
Try this:

```
function trans() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var row = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[2];
  var td = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

  td.innerHTML = "Julius";
}
```

You selected the first `tr` that has no `td` , only `th` in it and you also forgot `"s"` in `"getElementsByTagName"`.

Because with `"Tag"` you can get more then 1 element you need to add "s" , when it's by `ID` it makes sense that you will get only 1 item therefor no "s" is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `s` in your last line of Code.

Also, data already contains the element you want to edit, so there's no need to call `getElementsByTagName` on data.

Change this Line

```
data.getElementByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML = "Julius"
```

To

```
data.innerHTML = "Julius";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice.

```
function trans() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table"),
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[2],
      td = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];

      td.innerHTML = "Julius";
}
```

Issues:

1. In order to select a certain key "[2]" you need to use `.getElementsByTagName` instead of `.getElementsByTagName`;
2. You're targeting the wrong **tr**. There are tr's in the table head. So even with fixing the number 1 issue, you would not get the correct result.

Comment: no it wouldn't. please explain what the problem was and what you've changed.

Comment: The problem, as others previously stated was that `getElementByTagName` needed to be changed with `getElementsByTagName` from which we could pick a specific key (**[2]**), When this is fixed, the matter of making it work is simple. I have tested it and it works 100%.

Comment: Is the awsner better now? @Ted